# gcc - Using "-funsigned-char" still results in "-Wchar-subscripts" warnings

Tags: c, gcc

This isn't a question on how to prevent this warning but rather as to **why** I receive the warning at all.

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *str = "Hello World!";
    int   len = strlen(str);

    // Yes, a char, bare with me
    char index = 6;
    char seek  = 'Z';

    // Reject the string if str[index] != seek
    // Include some bounds checks for safety
    if (index < 0 || index >= len || str[index] != seek) {
        puts("Rejected");

    } else {
        puts("Kept");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile it with all warnings enabled, you get the following:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra char.c -o char
char.c: In function ‘main’:
char.c:15:5: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
     if (index < 0 || index >= len || str[index] != seek) {
     ^
```

Good!  By default, `char` can be signed and contain a negative value, so `str[index]` can cause problems if `index` is negative.

What if we force all `char`s to be unsigned with `-funsigned-char`?
That will guarantee that they will never be negative and should prevent the warning.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -funsigned-char char.c -o char
char.c: In function ‘main’:
char.c:15:15: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
     if (index < 0 || index >= len || str[index] != seek) {
               ^
char.c:15:5: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
     if (index < 0 || index >= len || str[index] != seek) {
     ^
```

`gcc` seems to be aware that `index < 0` will always be false because `index` is unsigned.  This explains the first warning.
However, it still warns about `str[index]` even though it knows that `index` will never be negative.

**Why does `gcc` still warn about char indexes when it already knows that it can never be negative?**

Comment: It cannot be negative on the current platform, but it could be on another one. The warning remains consistent across platforms, helping you write portable code. (I am not saying if I agree or not)

Comment: Because it is exactly how `-Wchar-subscripts` is specified?

Comment: Either use an `signed char` and cast to `size_t` if you definitively know it is not negative, or use `unsigned char` variables and remove the then useless test. In other words: don't fiddle on symptoms, but fix the actual fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-Wchar-subscripts` is intended as a portability warning. It tells you that *in general case* `char` can be signed. The fact that it is unsigned in your case is not relevant. If you don't care about general case - disable the warning.

Note, for example, that you will not receive a warning for `int` subscripts, even though `int` can be negative. The compiler assumes that you know what you are doing when you are using `int` for subscripts. But for `char` it wants to warn.

Note also that if you explicitly use `signed char` for subscripts in your code, the warning will disappear, even though `signed char` can definitely be negative. The compiler again assumes that you know what you are doing.